# С++. Структуры. Завершает работу после первого ввода

Tags: c++

Написал простое задание на тему структур, реализовал с помощью функций, сам код будет ниже. Вызывается 2 функции, создания и печати, если название нужного города совпадает с названием город в n-ной структуре. Без функций все работает нормально, если заносить в функции, то сначала вызывается функция создания(ввода), ввожу поле date(самая первая запись) и программу сразу же завершает работу. Почему так происходит? Сам код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct ATC{
    string date;
    string kod_name;
    float duration;
    float tarif;
    string numbercity;
    string number;
};

void createstruct(ATC *A, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<=n;i++) {
        cout << "Enter date: "; cin >> A[i].date;
        cout << "Enter kod_name: "; cin >> A[i].kod_name;
        cout << "Enter duration: "; cin >> A[i].duration;
        cout << "Enter tarif: "; cin >> A[i].tarif;
        cout << "Enter numbercity: "; cin >> A[i].numbercity;
        cout << "Enter number: "; cin >> A[i].number;
    }
     return;
}


void printstruct(ATC *A, int n, string city){
    int count(0);
    
    for (int i = 0; i<=n; i++){
        if (A[i].kod_name == city){
            count++;
            cout << A[i].date << endl << A[i].kod_name << endl << A[i].duration << endl << A[i].tarif << endl << A[i].number << endl << count << endl;
        }
    }
    return;
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter record count: "; cin >> n;
    struct ATC A[n];
    int key;
    string city;
    cout << "Enter city: "; cin >> city;
    

createstruct(&A[n], n);
printstruct(&A[n], n, city);

   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы не хотите поразмышлять, что Вы передаете в функции вот таким адресом `&A[n]`? Уж не следующий ли адрес после **последнего** элемента массива? Почему Вы не хотите передавать просто имя массива без операций взятия адреса? И как контрольный выстрел Вы еще делаете циклы до  `i<=n`... Почему же после всего этого насилия Вашей программе не "падать"?